# Build list of all Work Items along with their Story and Feature

Tags: sql, tfs

Does anyone know how i could build a query using TFS_Warehouse, that outputs something like:

```
Feature   Story     Task                  Estimated Hours  Completed Hours  Remaining Hours
F1        S1        Write Documentation   3                2                3
F1        S1        Write Code            10               4                2
F1        S2        Create Logo           5                1                1
F1        S2        Ship Logo             7                3                3
```

I would like each task listed, and then along with each task, list it's parent Story, and that story's parent Feature.  The purpose is to roll up the hours, and be able to pivot around Features and Stories and get totals.  I've searched the Microsoft documentation, but haven't found anything helpful yet.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to create a query I wanted:

```
use TFS_Warehouse;
-- first get the group of systemids we are interested in, either by iteration, or person, or
with systemids as (
   select system_id from DimWorkItem dwi 
   where 1=1
   --and dwi.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK=1332 -- (Russ)
   and dwi.IterationSK in(2590,2585,2593) -- Current W48, 
   --and dwi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate = 
   --and dwi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_FinishDate
   AND dwi.System_RevisedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999', 126) -- latest revision
)

,lvl12 as (
   select
          dwic.system_id as 'Feature System Id'
          ,dwic.System_Title + ' (' + dwic.System_WorkItemType + ') ' as Feature

          ,dwi.System_id as 'Story System Id'
          ,dwi.System_Title + ' (' + dwi.System_WorkItemType + ')' as Story

          ,wi.System_id as 'Work Item Id'
          ,wi.System_Title + ' (' + wi.System_WorkItemType + ')' as Task

          ,wi.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Activity as Activity

          ,fwi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate as OriginalEstimate
          ,fwi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork as RemainingWork
          ,fwi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork as CompletedWork

          ,p.Alias as 'Assigned To'
          ,p.PersonSK
          ,wi.System_State

          ,iteration.IterationPath
          ,iteration.IterationSK

          ,area.AreaName

          ,wi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate StartDate
          ,wi.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_FinishDate FinishDate

   FROM DimWorkItem wi
          -- used project id, found using another query
          CROSS APPLY GetWorkItemsTree('3F5639AD-05C7-4757-95D5-0DAB164E21B4', wi.system_id, N'Parent', DEFAULT) wit
          LEFT JOIN DimWorkItem dwi on dwi.WorkItemSK=wit.ParentWorkItemSK -- and dwi.System_WorkItemType='User Story'
          left join DimWorkItem dwic on dwic.WorkItemSK=wit.ChildWorkItemSK
          left join FactCurrentWorkItem fwi on fwi.WorkItemSK = wi.WorkItemSK
          left join DimPerson p on p.PersonSK = wi.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK
          left join DimIteration iteration on iteration.IterationSK = wi.IterationSK
          left join DimArea area on area.AreaSK = wi.AreaSK
   where 1=1
   AND wi.system_id in(select * from systemids)
   AND wi.System_RevisedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '9999', 126) -- latest revision
   AND wit.Level > 1
 )

select 
   lvl12.*
from lvl12
order by Feature, Story, Task
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is creating a **Tree of work items** query, then open the query in Excel. Then render the format as you required and save as a new Excel sheet.

You can follow the steps marked in below screenshot to do that.

Reference : [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel)

[image]

Comment: @russds Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update?

Comment: Thank you for the great response.  I was looking for a SQL query to use against the database TFS_Warehouse.  I was finally able to get what I was looking for.  Thanks again!